# Передача данных клиент-сервер node.js

Tags: node.js, javascript

Здравствуйте.

1. Как осуществляется передача данных с клиента на сервер и с сервера на клиент в чистом node.js?
2. Можно ли использовать функции сервера на клиенте?

Comment: 1. через библиотеку http например (`var http = require('http');`)
2. можно не писать заново модели, но естественно память на клиенте и сервере разная.

Answer (score 1):

Не дурите голову человеку, сокеты нужны только для дуплексного соединения между клиентом и сервером. Для стандартного обмена данными используется модули ноды http или express.js. (Второй основан на первом, но мощнее по функционалу) вот примеры http://expressjs.com/ru/guide/routing.html :

```
var express = require('express')
```

Идея в том, что обратившись к сайту через браузер просто набрав нужный адрес, например http://localhost:3000/ (если на локалке) или http://yoursite.com/, если сайт на хостинге, вы отправляете запрос GET "/" на ваш сервер, его можно обработать роутером (обработчиком пути) вот так:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});
```

Вместо 'Hello World' можно отправить HTML страницу, например. Так же делаются и остальные страницы сайта, например http://yoursite.com/page/:

```
app.get('/page', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Another page!');
});
```

Если мы хотим с браузера **отправить данные** на сервак, то мы отправляем стандартную форму кнопкой submit, например, или AJAX POST (простой пример на jQuery):

```
<script>
    $("submit").click(function(){
         jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'name=vasya',
            success: function (resp) {
                alert(resp);
            },
            error: function (xhr, str) {
                alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Этот код надо поместить на страничку, с которой мы будет отправлять данные на сервер. Тогда на сервере надо написать обработчик этого запроса. Для этого подключим модуль парсинга запросов:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

А теперь им обработаем запрос с помощью express:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var name = req.body.name,
        res.send('Your name is ' + name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Рекомендую обратить внимание на вебсокеты в node.js

2) Почитайте про meteor для node.js

Comment: а что есть в метеоре чего нету в чистом nodejs? нужен фреймворк для веб сайта в связке нода - реакт, какой лучше рассматривать модній метеор или класический експрес?

Comment: Не дурите голову человеку, сокеты нужны только для дуплексного соединения между клиентом и сервером. Для стандартного обмена данными используется модули ноды http или express.js.